# How do you justify-evenly with borders in Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm wondering if it's at all possible in purely TailwindCSS to evenly justify columns with a gutter separating them? Currently the only way I could achieve this is to:

- On the parent provide it with `flex`, `justify-evenly` and use `divide-x`
- On each child in the panel use `w-full` and pad them according to their position ie. first doesn't pad left and further right doesn't pad right, the middle padding evenly.

Here's an example of the result I'm hoping to achieve:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of ideas for you, both work pretty well if you were to just drop in a 4th column/item too. I've added links to Tailwind play where I fully coded both options.

## Option A: Borders & first-child / last-child

Spaced with `flex` & `flex-1`, borders are used for dividers. x-child handles removing where necessary.

[Full code on Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EjC6urmPvs) | [Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLYKs.png)

```css
@layer components {
  .item {
    @apply flex-1 px-5 border-r border-solid border-neutral-200;
  }
  .item:first-child {
    @apply pl-0;
  }
  .item:last-child {
    @apply pr-0 border-0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> 
  <hr />
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
      <p class="title">Ready to drink</p>
      <p class="count">31</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="title">Expiring Soon</p>
      <p class="count">23</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="title">Past Prime</p>
      <p class="count">32</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Option B: Dividers as divs

Spaced using `flex`, `flex-1` & `gap-5` if you are happy to make your dividers additional elements.

[Full code on Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2cD3KgysoH) | [Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfW8Z.png)

```html
<div class="card"> 
  <hr />
  <div class="flex gap-5">
    <div class="flex-1 bg-green-100">
      <p class="title">Ready to drink</p>
      <p class="count">31</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-neutral-200 w-[1px]"></div> <!-- Divider -->
    <div class="flex-1 bg-orange-100">
      <p class="title">Expiring Soon</p>
      <p class="count">23</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-neutral-200 w-[1px]"></div> <!-- Divider -->
    <div class="flex-1 bg-red-100">
      <p class="title">Past Prime</p>
      <p class="count">32</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought about these as options.

Comment: Option B is the perfect solution